# magento 2.4 add cms block to minicart

Tags: magento2.4, mini-cart, cms-block

I'm using widgets to insert static blocks on different places in my magento website. It works everywhere except the minicart. When I create a widget with the layout `minicart promotion block`, what I expect is to see my block content visible when I open the minicart. Instead, the content of the static block is visible during page load, then it disappears.

Is there a way to avoid the page load issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think What you did is perfect, that is the way to show CMS block in minicart, maybe if you provide your widget setting then maybe we can check and provide some information